# Using Alt Key in FakeVim mode of Qt Creator?

Tags: qt-creator, fakevim

It's really handy when you work with **VIM** text editor to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to execute normal mode commands in insert mode, for example when you are in insert mode you can press <kbd>Alt + j</kbd> to go one line down. But in FakeVim mode of Qt creator this couldn't be done. Any suggestion is welcome.
Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> each time you want to go to normal mode really sucks.

Answer (score 1):

(not a fix to your problem, just discussing it in a properly formatted text)

I never hit `<ESC>` as well, and this is a deal breaker for me. Note that it's not a vim feature, though : this behavior occurs because using Alt with an other key in terminals generates an escape sequence. So there's nothing wrong with FakeVim regarding Alt implementation, the problem is related to the IDE being a QT window. You can't use Alt sequence in GTK's Gvim as well, for the same reason, last time I checked.

A possible easy fix on the QCreator part : provide an option to not pass Alt combinations, like the one existing for Ctrl. That is, if QT allows that. We could then at the very least define vim bindings using Alt key to simulate the terminal behavior.

In the list of others exotic combinations from terminals that quickly lead to form habits in vim, I also use `C-j` in place of `<return>`, and `C-h` instead of `<backspace>`. Those would really be nice to have too :)

Comment: :D Sorry, I just feel not at ease in SO comment oneliners :)